# How do I add a custom style to node by its type?

Tags: theming

I've tried following the instructions on http://drupal.org/node/1089656, but I somehow can't get it right.

How do I apply custom layout/style to a node based on its type?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let me also suggest you look into the Display Suite module (drupal.org/project/ds) as it will give you a friendly interface to drag-and-drop the display of fields into regions depending on the content type. Can be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content type of the node is Article, then the template file Drupal looks for is node--article.tpl.php.
If the content type name contains underscores, those are replaced with hyphens. If the content type machine name is snippet_code, then the template filename is node--snippet-code.tpl.php.

Comment: and the OP shouldn't forget to [clear the (theme registry) cache](http://drupal.org/node/42055) after putting the template file into his/her theme's templates directory. :)

Comment: That's correct: The cache must be cleaned, or the theme must be disabled, and renamed.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out asap and let you know how it went